Static DHCP working over 2.4Ghz but not on 5Ghz WiFi
I am trying to learn assigning static IP address to my PC. I use zyxel wifi router and added my mac address for static ip assignment. Now my router has two separate bands 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz.
This is the output of ip a when the PC is not connected to Wifi
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:46:5c:45:70:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

This is the ip a output post connecting to 2.4Ghz
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:46:5c:45:70:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 86394sec preferred_lft 86394sec
    inet6 2401:4900:1cb0:288b:c21a:cf1d:5a4a:327c/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 84841sec preferred_lft 84841sec
    inet6 2401:4900:1cb0:288b:33b2:9fb7:693a:fa13/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 84841sec preferred_lft 84841sec
    inet6 fe80::4ea5:a545:d2d0:4302/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Output of iwconfig wlp3s0
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Airtel_D_604"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 14:33:75:01:F5:BF   
          Bit Rate=234 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=53/70  Signal level=-57 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0


This is the router configuration of the connected device
enter image description here
Now when I connect to 5Ghz network these are the below details.
output of ip a
wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:46:5c:45:70:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.12/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 86382sec preferred_lft 86382sec
    inet6 2401:4900:1cb0:82cd:60f2:110a:ae7d:550a/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 86315sec preferred_lft 86039sec
    inet6 2401:4900:1cb0:82cd:e048:1567:344:56a5/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86315sec preferred_lft 86315sec
    inet6 fe80::6d7f:7469:6cd7:eaf3/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Output of iwconfig wlp3s0
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Airtel_D_604_5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: CC:B1:82:27:13:FC   
          Bit Rate=585 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:4   Missed beacon:0


This is the router configuration of the connected device enter image description here
Due to different MAC address being logged in router I am not able to assign single static IP address to my PC.
Why is router getting different MAC address when getting connected to different Wifi even though the ip a is giving same MAC address in output

What actually happens when you connect to 5GHz – do you get a different address from the same subnet, or do you get an address from an entirely different subnet? (Each band works as a separate access point – it's entirely possible for them to be disjoint – so it sounds as if the 5GHz AP on your router was accidentally removed from its LAN bridge config...)

I get different private address from same subnet-mask. Also in the router configuration I don't see an option to assign static ip at band level. I also tried by switching between different wifi band, whenever I would connect to the 2.5Ghz it would assign the correct static IP but then assign a new IP over 5Ghz

When you connect over 5GHz, does the client show up in the router's DHCP lease table? Does it have the same MAC address? Does the router show a "Client ID" field, and does the client show the same client ID both ways? (Client ID is usually MAC-based, but not on every OS.)

You need to configure the 2.4 GHz radio separate from the 5 GHz radio. I do believe you mean 2.4 GHz instead of 2.5 GHz since there is no Wi-Fi standard that uses 2.5 GHz

Yes I meant 2.4Ghz. updated the question. There is no option in zyxel router to assign IP for separate bands. Neither does it does the list of connected devices and their current IPs. Let me add screenshots in the question

In every router I have had, consider the 2.4 GHz a separate network from the 5.0 GHz network.

It looks like I know the first level root cause but don't the reason for it. The root cause of it is that MAC address is different in router connected item list hence router  dishes out new ip. Added details in the main question

What access point BSSID does iw wlp3s0 link (or iwconfig wlp3s0 if it's old) show when connected to each band? Do they both match the Zyxel Wi-Fi interface MAC address? Do you have any 2.4GHz "Wifi extender" in use?

I am not aware what's BSSID access point. I did add the output of ip a not sure if above access point is present there. And yes I do have Wifi Extender but not sure if it for 2.4Ghz or 5Ghz bandwidth

It's not present there, hence me specifically asking for the output of iw wlp3s0 link instead.

Added output of iwconfig wlp3s0 to the question itself

According to the Access Point field shown by iwconfig (which has the MAC address of the specific Wi-Fi access point – aka the BSSID), you are connecting to two different devices on the two bands.
The address 14:33:75:01:F5:BF that's shown on the 2.4 GHz band is one that was issued by Zyxel, as expected, but on the 5 GHz band you are connecting to CC:B1:82:27:13:FC – a completely different MAC address that belongs to a Huawei device (according to the CC:B1:82 prefix).
It's likely that you have a Wi-Fi extender or something similar that broadcasts a Wi-Fi network with the same SSID (network name), and due to the way extenders work, it cannot pass-through its clients' real MAC addresses. Or something like that.  Since it uses the same network name as your router, client devices connect to the nearest one.
Use iwlist wlp3s0 scan or nmcli dev wifi list or various Android "Wi-Fi analyzer" style apps to see all nearby access points individually (i.e. not grouped by name), together with their signal strength – it should help you track down the unwanted AP. (I think iOS has a similar scanner hidden within the "AirPort Utility" app.)

Thank you for the deep dive, Can you clarify what did you mean by "unwanted AP" What's an AP?

I tried shutting down the extended and then connecting to different wifi bands. It does work and it gets same static ip all the time. However the access point is still different
for 5Ghz wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Airtel_D_604_5G"             Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 0E:33:75:01:F5:BF for 2.4Ghz wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Airtel_D_604"             Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: 14:33:75:01:F5:BF 

"Access point" – the actual device (either standalone or part of a router) that broadcasts a Wi-Fi connection. Your router has a dual-band Wi-Fi AP, but a larger Wi-Fi network can actually consist of many APs (connected to a single router) and seamlessly roam between them for best signal; that's how extenders work as well (every extender is an AP plus a client).

0E:33:75:01:F5:BF is close enough that it might be correct. It's very common for the same router or access point to have slightly different MACs for different bands – each manufacturer does it differently, some differ in the 1st byte, others in the last byte, etc. – so I'd say you should check the Zyxel router's settings pages to see what WiFi MAC or BSSID it shows for each band, but it's likely to be the correct device.

hi @grawity_u1686. Post your comment went though other posts and documents to understand BSSID, SSID, network analyzer. However my problem still persists that my PC is not able to get static IP. Would you happen to know any solution for such cases? Added a separate question with details at  https://superuser.com/questions/1858936/unable-to-get-private-static-ip-when-using-wifi-extender
