Unable to get private static IP when using WiFi extender
I have a zyxel WiFi router and huawei extender. Both of them provide dual band WiFi's with same SSID(wifi name) and with different BSSID.
The private IP address being assigned are 192.168.X.X and I would use 192.168.1.1 to access configuration.
I have assigned static private IP in my WiFi's configuration corresponding to my PCs MAC address.
Whenever I connect to WiFi corresponding to my router's BSSID it works perfectly fine and I get private static IP. However when my PC automatically switches to extenders BSSID, my PCs MAC gets masked and my rounter assigns new IP to my PC since the MAC is different.
As per few posts I read, it asked me to disable DHCP from my extender, however I am unable to view web-based configuration for my extender.
So I have below questions

Is it possible to trigger private IP assignment from my PC itself, that way I can get the same IP regardless of BSSID?
Else how do I assign private IP when using extender?
How do I veiw my extenders configuration? Whenever I go to 192.168.1.1 it takes me to router's configuration page regardless of whichever BSSID I am connected to.

Also one of the solution I can think of is to specify the BSSID at my PC for a given Wifi. This will ensure I always connect to my router's network but then I would be forced to have lower speed since the network is weak. If I specify my extender's BSSID then also the masked MAC address changes post power cut/reboot

Some extenders will do MAC masking, but it should always be the same MAC-Mask pair for that device. You can assign a static IP for both MACs. For seamless roaming, you usually need a "mesh" configured, so the router and extender can let each other know where your device is connected to
